# How can I run a sequence of applications or actions on certain triggers on Android?

Tags: automation

Is there is free application or some trick to run sequence of applications on android?
For example I want to start the following sequence:
    **Wi-Fi --> Tor --> Browser**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5ldC5kaW5nbGlzY2guYW5kcm9pZC50YXNrZXJtIl0.) for simple interface and quick setup.

If you are willing to do something by code and very specific, a good alternative is [onX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.onx.app&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5taWNyb3NvZnQub254LmFwcCJd) by Microsoft, you can write your code to do exactly the things you wanna do. Also there are some ready recipes that you can quickly setup.

Answer (score 0):

For newer phones, you can use Automagic, which has almost all of the functionality of Tasker (at the time of this writing, and expanding) and has a *much* better interface for editing your sequences. It also makes use of the newer Holo themes on Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) and later.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler automation apps can probably only start a single app, or maybe more, but not in sequence. The more advanced apps that can perform this is either the trusted old [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (paid), or the newer [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=automate) (free).