# Turn notifications on and off based on time periods

Tags: settings, notifications, automation

Is there a way to configure Android to turn off notifications at a specific time and turn them on at a specific time? Pretty much I don't want to hear notifications at 3 AM from anyone or anything.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33678/how-can-i-run-a-sequence-of-applications-or-actions-on-certain-triggers-on-andro). Take a look at this topic, it might help you

Comment: @Markissimo No, not really. That other question is more about "Makro Mode", i.e. "first run X, then Y, then Z". This here is about "Change setting at X (time), and change back at Y (other time)". Though the best answer (Tasker) is the same in both cases :)

Comment: Closely related: [Can I silence only certain notifications during the night?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29731/can-i-silence-only-certain-notifications-during-the-night)

Answer (score 2):

There are several automation apps in the playstore which deal with this kind of subject. Some of them are simply time-based (which would match your question), such as e.g. [Timeriffic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBWiq.jpg)</sup> -- others additionally can react on other conditions like location, calendar and more (e.g. [MyProfiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fancy01.myprofiles.lite)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUjQa.jpg)</sup>). The top end of flexibility can be reached with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) -- there's almost nothing this app couldn't do. It needs some time to get used to, and costs some money, but for sure it's worth it.

[image: Timeriffic] [image: MyProfiles]

There are a lot of more apps like the mentioned ones, so just take them as examples for further "investigation" in the playstore. There also is a German listing on AndroidPIT ([Automatisierung -- Profile-Switcher & Co](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/423710/) -- [Google Translate Version](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.de%2Fde%2Fandroid%2Fforum%2Fthread%2F423710%2FUebersicht-Automatisierung-Profile-Switcher-Co)) to give you a faster start looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Cyanogenmod there's `Settings->CyanogenMod Settings->Sound->Quiet Hours`.

Comment: Is it possible to schedule when those quite hours are throughout the day? The reason I ask is because I am looking for something that would snooze notifications, meaning still be able to receive them eventually, just not while I am busy doing something so that I do not get distracted.

Answer (score 2):

"Do not disturb" mode should be present in stock and skinned Android versions. It can be accessed through the Settings. You can set which apps can send what notifications at what time.

The main benefit is no third-party app needs to be installed.

Comment: The nice thing here is that you can very easily set it to stay in "do not disturb" mode for a specific amount of time, so you don't need to remember to turn it off manually.

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Galaxy S4 has a blocking mode that you can only receive calls or notification of calls in between certain times...unless you put people on a contact allowed list...not sure how this will work with texts.