# Hiding all Android notifications until scheduled time

Tags: notifications

Is it possible on Android to set a schedule or even just a single timer during which all notifications will be hidden but stored and shown at a specific scheduled time?

For example, let's say I want to focus for a day, so I decide that I still want my notifications, but I only want to see them at noon and at 4pm. I want all the notifications before noon to be sent to me at exactly noon. And all the notifications between noon and 4pm to be sent to me at exactly 4pm.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Possibly related/duplicate: [Turn notifications on and off based on time periods](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/33686/44325), particularly the DnD mode for newer Android.

Comment: And if you're not yet on Android 13, you might find a fitting app [in my corresponding app listing here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications).

Answer (score 1):

You may have two good options for this, depending on your phone model and software version:

## [Focus mode](https://www.android.com/digital-wellbeing/#productivity-get-stuff-done)

Focus mod was made available generally in Android 13 and can be set on a schedule by going to *Settings > Digital Wellbeing & parental controls > Focus mode*. While focus mode is on, notifications will be held from the apps you select ("distracting" apps), and you won't see them until Focus Mode is paused or disabled.

- Pros:

  - Holds notifications for you on a set schedule
  - Will allow you to "take a break" at any time to see pending notifications (at noon)
- Cons:

  - Can't break up the schedule without using the "take a break" feature
  - This mode also disables these apps, attempting to keep you from using them at all, in addition to holding their notifications

## [Do not disturb](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9069335?hl=en)

Do Not Disturb can be accessed through *Settings > Sound & vibration > Do Not Disturb* and allows you to set Schedules. You can set two schedules (beginning of the day until noon, 12:15 pm to 4 pm) during which notifications will be hidden until Do Not Disturb is turned off.

- Pros:

  - You can set the exact schedule you're looking for
  - You can still choose what alerts your phone (apps, calls, alarms, etc.)
- Cons:

  - The intention of Do Not Disturb is to block *most or all* communication from your phone, so you'll want to be careful about the settings, including who can call, what apps can interrupt, and how to handle alarms, media sounds, etc.
  - Using these settings for this purpose will change the way Do Not Disturb acts all the time. For instance, if you use this to allow calls through but block app notifications, the same settings will apply when you use Do Not Disturb in a movie theater, and a call may come through.